# Can Drupal 8 core's Tour module be used for public facing pages?

Tags: 8

I'm interested in learning more about the Tour module.  The docs don't specify anything about if it can be used for public facing pages, just admin pages.

If you can, what would the "route" be for public URLs?  At some point the module switched to using routes, rather than paths.

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: I just read the documentation page (https://www.drupal.org/node/1934442), and it doesn't say anything about it being only for admin pages, so I suspect it's fine on any page.

Comment: This page talks a lot about administrative pages https://www.drupal.org/contributor-tasks/create-tour but that could be task related.